# How to parse a string to collect particular data as list using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

There is a string incoming from remote source. I need to create an array of "UserId" from that string, I think regex is might be useful to achieve this:

```
var data = "ice cream #pozaa #tea [UserId:1],\n[UserId:345],\n[UserId:1456]\n"

var expectedResult = [1,345,1456]
```

how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible way:

```js
const input = "ice cream #pozaa #tea [UserId:1],\n[UserId:345],\n[UserId:1456]\n";
let result = [...input.matchAll(/\[UserId:(\d+)\]/g)].map(m => +m[1]);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just use `match()`:

```js
var data = "ice cream 123[nope:8]#pozaa #tea [UserId:1],\n[UserId:345],\n[UserId:1456]\n";

console.log(data.match(/\d+/g)); // finds all numbers
console.log(data.match(/\[UserId:\d+\]/g)); // finds UserIds only
console.log(data.match(/\[UserId:\d+\]/g).map(s=>parseInt(s.match(/\d+/)))); // with parsing
```

Added some extra trash, but for the orginal example data the first one could work already.

Answer (score 0):

You can use lookbehinds:

- `(?<=y)x` – positive lookbehinds (matches 'x' when it's precede by 'y')
- `(?<!y)x` – negative lookbehinds (matches 'x' when it's not precede by 'y')

```js
const data = 'ice cream #pozaa #tea [UserId:1],\n[UserId:345],\n[UserId:1456]\n';

const ids = data
  // select all ids and return an array of strings, example: ["1", "345", "1456"]
  .match(/(?<=UserId:)(\d+)/gi)
  // converts the entire array from string to number, example: ["1", "345", "1456"] -> [1, 345, 1456]
  .map(Number);

console.log(ids);
```

Answer (score -2):

You have to use Pattern and Matcher classes from Java. It will help you get by the matching number and then you can get the group using group capture. Like here in your case using regex UserId:(\d+) you will get the user id.

```
List<String> userID = new ArrayList<String>();
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("UserId:(\\d+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(<ex_input>);
while(matcher.find()) {
 userID.add(matcher.group(0));
}
```

Comment: There are *a couple* of differences between `JavaScript` and `Java` and the answer is just plain wrong.

Comment: And why do you think so that this answer is wrong for Java?

Comment: It is not wrong for `Java` but does not answer the question. A solution in e.g. `Python` or `Lisp` would also not answer the question, would it?

Comment: Yes, it wouldn't. True.